# Paypal custom text on payment page

Tags: php, paypal

I am using set express checkout to get payment authorization from users in order to do reference transactions in future. However on payment page there is a message:

"You’ll be able to see your details before you pay"

I want this message to be replaced by my order description. I found that only way of doing that is passing details in < ebl:PaymentDetailsItem>. But when I do this, there is an extra item quantity showing up with payment details: e.g. Quantity: 1 but in my case quantity is irrelevant as I am just authorizing user's Paypal account and creating billing agreement id.

Is there any way to remove the quantity in description. I want to remove the "You’ll be able to see...."  message thats it.

Regards
Kashif

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what parameters you are passing in but when I pass the below parameters to my **"SetExpressCheckout"** API call with the description in "L_BILLINGAGREEMENTDESCRIPTION0" variable then it shows correctly without any quantity details :

**NVP Request:**

```
USER=XXXXXXXXX&PWD=XXXXXXXXXX&SIGNATURE=XXXXXXXXXXX&VERSION=109.0&METHOD=SetExpressCheckout&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION=AUTHORIZATION&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE=USD&L_BILLINGTYPE0=MerchantInitiatedBilling&L_BILLINGAGREEMENTDESCRIPTION0=ClubUsage&cancelUrl=http://www.yourdomain.com/cancel.html&returnUrl=http://www.yourdomain.com/success.html
```

**NVP Response:**

```
TOKEN=EC-46J52482MC115554L
TIMESTAMP=2014-09-30T09:10:48Z
CORRELATIONID=14fde6edcdc6
ACK=Success
VERSION=109.0
BUILD=13077960
```

And when I redirect my buyer to :

https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&token=EC-46J52482MC115554L

I get the following screen which shows the description that I passed in my API call :

[image]

Comment: Thanks Eshan,
 Just one more thing how can I achieve similar result when I am actually selling the product(i.e. charging amount from user). In that case also, Quantity is not relevant too.

Thanks & Regards \

Comment: Can you post a sample request in selling product scenario?

Comment: `code`
<ns2:SetExpressCheckoutReq xsi:type="SetExpressCheckoutRequest">
<SetExpressCheckoutRequest xsi:type="ns2:SetExpressCheckoutRequestType">
<ns1:Version>117</ns1:Version>
<ns1:SetExpressCheckoutRequestDetails>
<ns1:ReturnURL>...</ns1:ReturnURL>
<ns1:CancelURL>...</ns1:CancelURL>
<ns1:OrderDescription>Data recovery Service</ns1:OrderDescription>
<ns1:PaymentAction>Sale</ns1:PaymentAction>
<ns1:PaymentDetails>
<ns1:OrderTotal currencyID="USD">5.85</ns1:OrderTotal>
</ns1:PaymentDetails>
</ns1:SetExpressCheckoutRequestDetails>
</SetExpressCheckoutRequest>
</ns2:SetExpressCheckoutReq>
`code`

Comment: Hi Eshan,
Do you have any update on this yet?
Regards 
kashif